# GWT HTML not showing line breaks

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm trying to display a GWT UiField HTML object with line breaks, but it doesn't seem to work.

I accept a string, sanitize it using the `SimpleHtmlSanitizer`, and then the line breaks display as text instead of html in the AlertWidget, which is a `DialogBox`.

```
@UiField
HTML description;

public AlertWidget(String htmlMessage) {
    SafeHtml safeMessage = SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml(htmlMessage);
    setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    this.description.setHTML(safeMessage);
}
```

On the page, the contents of the dialog box end up looking exactly like the input String:

```
The first error<br>the second error
```

I can see in my ide that the sanitized SafeHtml contains the `safe` value:

```
The first error&lt;br&gt;the second error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [sanitizeHtml](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SimpleHtmlSanitizer.html#sanitizeHtml(java.lang.String)).  At the top there's a list of supported tags. The break line tag is not supported.

I'd try some other mechanism for creating the SafeHTML:

- http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlBuilder.html

Comment: Huh. Sounds like GWT's basic policy in terms of ensure HTML is safe is DIY. Thanks for the reference to the Javadoc. Plain HTML should be fine for this anyway.

Comment: @CorayThan I've edited the answer.  It looks like you can define your own sanitizer using the SafeHtmlBuilder.

Comment: I was able to use `SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(error)` to construct a SafeHtml, because in this case it is a trusted string. I was hoping I could make one generic method that could sanitize everything all the time, but for now I'll just handle it on a case-by-case basis.